# ADO Error: 0x80040e14 exception occurred in microsoft oledb provider for odbc drivers[ODBC 8.0(a)][mysqld-8.0.20] You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-workbench, labview, rfid

We have built RFID based system identification application in LabView using MySQL as database.

We have one same software running on two similar computers. Few months before application was running properly on both the computers. Now one is running smoothly but the second one gives following error.

***ADO error: 0x80040e14 exception occurred in microsoft ole db provider for odbc drivers [MYSQL] [ODBC 8.0(a)] [mysqld-8.0.20] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual corresponds to your MySQL version for the right syntax yo user near "RFID_tag_number' at line 1 in NI_Database_API.lvlib:Conn Execute.vi...till path of the file.***

As you can see there is double inverted comma before RFID_tag_number in the error, but in our code we have only used single inverted comma as it is a string value. We tried to copy complete application from the computer where it is properly running to the second computer but still getting the same error.

The only difference between both computers we found is -
In the computer running properly - In MySQL Workbench >Administrator >Server Status, the Configuration Path is ***My SQL Server 5.7\my.ini***

And in the second computer it is ***My SQL Server 8.0\my.ini***.

We don't know if this is the reason for the error or how the configuration path affects the application. We even tried to remove MySQL server 8.0 completely from computer with the issue and installed MySQL server 5.7 but still the path remained same.

Can anyone help us? We are new to LabView working with MySQL.

Comment: Check the system localization setup. LV might be replacing a single quote with a double due to locallization.

Answer (score 0):

What I  understand,  error will throw for incorrect query,it might be required handling special characters.
Second if same data base access  by both system
,system required same version my mysql and odbc driver also.
Third, when you try to remove mysql, delete hidden files in c drive then install new version

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. The system where we are facing issues shows My SQL Server 8.0\my.ini as configuration path, we removed the SQL server completely, deleted all folders including hidden. Installed MySQL version 5.7 but after installing workbench, the configuration path still shows My SQL Server 8.0\my.ini. Any solution for this?